How to filter a ComplexTypeCollection field in Azure Search to find records containing specific text?
I'm using Azure Search and have an index with a field of type ComplexTypeCollection called ComplexField. Each item in ComplexField has a text property called TextProperty.
I would like to know how to apply a filter on ComplexField to retrieve all records where TextProperty contains a specific text. For example, if the search text is "example," I want to get all records where at least one of the items in ComplexField has TextProperty that contains the string "example."
Here are the details of the ComplexField:
{
  "name": "ComplexField",
  "type": "Collection(Edm.ComplexType)",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "Id",
      "type": "Edm.Int32",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "vectorEncoding": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "TextProperty",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "vectorEncoding": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    }
  ]
}

Here is an example of the data structure:
{
  "records": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "ComplexField": [
        { "TextProperty": "example text" },
        { "TextProperty": "another text" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "ComplexField": [
        { "TextProperty": "some text" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


How can I write a query to get all records where TextProperty in ComplexField contains "example"? Do I need to change any field properties to make this work?
Thanks in advance for your help!

refer to this doc for Model complex data types in Azure AI Search

Can you try this syntax: ~/yourservice?$filter=ComplexTypeCollection/any(a: contains( a/TextProject,'Sample')

To filter ComplexTypeCollection fields in Azure Cognitive Search based on the contents of a nested TextProperty, you can use OData filtering syntax, since the TextProperty in your ComplexField collection is set as filterable.
Below is the sample example  :
  { 
  "name": "FieldName", 
  "type": "Edm.ComplexType",
  "fields": [
    { 
      "name": "SubFieldName1", 
      "type": "Edm.String", 
      "filterable": false, 
      "sortable": false, 
      "facetable": false, 
      "searchable": true 
    },
    { 
      "name": "SubFieldName2", 
      "type": "Edm.String", 
      "searchable": true, 
      "filterable": true, 
      "sortable": true, 
      "facetable": true 
    }
  ]
}



Update your index and filter the collection by using any to filter on a specific condition within the collection.
The following filter query retrieves records where any item in ComplexField has a TextProperty containing the exact phrase, as shown below:
$filter=ComplexField/any(c: contains(c/TextProperty, 'example'))


I followed this link to update an index, using this sample example of a complex structure from this documentation1.


I have added documents to Azure AI Search index using this guide, based on the above complex type and following the example from docment1.

I followed this link for text query filters in Azure AI Search, using the OData filter.
Output :

